# application request routing client affinity with multiple arr servers

Tags: iis-7.5, arr

When multiple ARR servers are used as in the image below:[image]

Will the ARR server honour client affinity requests, irrespective of which ARR server handles an incoming request? The client passes a cookie in the headers, but the value appears to be an encoded string. I'm not sure if ARR 2 will be able to interpret a value generated on ARR 1 and route the client request to the affinitized server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once the client affinity cookie is created by an ARR server, the cookie will work on any other ARR server, provided the two (or more) ARR servers share the same Web Farm configuration.

Reference: I'm the current owner of ARR.